# In SAS Data Intergration, Create a user written transformation to skip further job execution without giving an error when certain condition is true

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-dis

I want to create a user written transformation to skip further job execution when certain condition is true.
I have tried the code

```
        %abort;
        %abort cancel;
```

but these statements gives error, something like Stopped processing because of %abort statement.
I don't want an error message to be displayed, just skip the remaining job execution. e.g. If my source table has zero observations then get out of the job without logging error message or warning.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, not sure if this will work in SAS DI (I don't have it to test), but what we use is the below macro:

```
%macro stop_sas;
  %if "&sysenv" eq "FORE" %then %do;
    %abort cancel;
  %end;
  %else %do;
    endsas;
  %end;
%mend;
```

It basically checks to see if SAS is running as a batch job or not, and if it is, quits SAS quietly.  If SAS is running in interactive mode, then it will just abort the submitted code, without closing the IDE.

The key statement here is the `endsas` command - which is probably the part you are looking for.

Comment: is there any way like directly jump to postcode, execute it & finish the job when condition is evaluated to true from the user written transformation

Comment: I don't believe so. SAS has a very poor list of options for error handling.

Comment: Note that the above macro does not work with EG nor SAS Studio.